# Python packaging-How to read files in a relative path

Tags: python, path, package

I use `setuptools` to distribute a python package. My directory structure is like following.

```
Mypackage
--setup.py
--my_package.py
Data
  --some_name.log
```

I want users to put data files in this folder, and name can be anything with the extension .log.

```
log_list = []
for file in glob.glob('/home/ginger/Mypackage/Data/*.log'):
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                try:
                    data = p.parse(line)
                except:
                    pass
            log_list.append(data)
```

This code works fine. But when I try to get the absolute path from the relative path it does not read the data file. Why is this?

```
path = os.path.abspath("Data/*.log")

    log = []
    for file in glob.glob(path):
        with open(file,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                log.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Path has to be defined as following with the immediate directory.

```
path = os.path.abspath("Mypackage/Data/*.log")
```